# Finding The Big Number using if else condition Python

Tags: python

I want to find the big number. But after compile, it showing b value. But c is the big number of all those.

```
a= 21
b=22
c= 23

if a>(b&c):
    print(a)
elif b>(c&a):
    print(b)
else :
    print(c)
```

Comment: why do you need the bitwise and in there?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Comment: Please also brush up on the difference between a [bitwise AND `&`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) and [the `and` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use logical "and" instead of bit wise &. You can use like below using logical and operator.

```
a= 21
b=22 
c= 23 
if (a>b) and (a>c):
   print(a) 
elif (b>c) and (b>a): 
   print(b) 
else: 
   print(c)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you ...

Comment: You probably really want `>=` instead of `>`.  The above code will fail if `a == b` but both are bigger than `c`.  It'll incorrectly print out `c`.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is just `max(a, b, c)`

Comment: No, I need only using if-else conditions.

Comment: @SurajitSinghaSisir Huh? This is a vastly superior way of accomplishing this, in more ways than one. Why do you "*need... if-else conditions*"?

Comment: If you really can't use `max`, then use the solution below, but note my comments.  You want >= instead of >.

Comment: @esqew.  I suspect this is a homework assignment.